# how to insert data into an sq-lite database at runtime

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, runtime

I built an application that uses sq-lite database and within the application at run-time i made a button that when pressed added a new Edit-Text i'm wondering how can i save the values in the new Edit-Text into my database? please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use this method :

```
public long saveData(Context context, String editTextValue) {
        long x = -1;
        appDb = new AppDatabase(context);
        sqliteDb = appDb.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("monthOfBirth", editTextValue);
        try {
            if (sqliteDb.isOpen()) {
                x = sqliteDb.insert("password", null, values);
                if (x >= 0)
                {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Password Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Call this method in your `button's onClickListener()`

```
button.setOnCLickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
{
    @override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         if(editText.getText().toString.equals(""))
         {
             Toast.makeText(context, "Fill Value first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;
         }
         saveData(YourActivity.this, editText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the class extending SQLiteOpenHelper? If you have it, then use the constructor and get an object of this class:

```
dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, getString(R.string.db_name_dev), null, DB_VERSION);
```

And then for example:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("term", term);
db.insert("Search", null, cv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a String which contains insert query of SQL. Then call the method

```
db.execSQL(sql);
```

on your datebase refence variable.

```
String sql =
            "INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> VALUES('this is','03/04/2005','5000','tran','y')" ;       
            db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: Why must a string be used??? And insert is not a query!

Comment: u should use string to write the query.

Comment: `db.execSQL("INSERT ...");` is absolutely same and doesn't need extra variable...